# Python create list of 1 element if the element exist in another list

Tags: python, list

i have list :

```
var1 = "aaa"
var2 = "bbb"
var3 = "ccc"
var4 = "ddd"
l = [var1,var2,var3,var4]
```

now I like to find if string exists in this list so i do :

```
x = "bbb"
if x in l:
```

in this case, it exists, but now i like to create new list that contains only 1 element which is x
is there any short way to create list that contains only x
this do not work

```
if x in l:
   l = [x for X in l]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this with a single list comprehension:

```
result = [element for element in mylist if element == x]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a list of one element even it appears in the list multiple times, you can write the following:

```
l1 = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd']
x = 'bbb'

l2 = [x] if x in l1 else []
```